# Flexible grid layout to list addresses

Tags: lists, grid-typesetting

I've been using LaTeX to typeset my CV for quite a few years now, and I've always had one nagging problem that I've never quite managed to solve adequately.

The very last section in my CV is always a list of references. As my credentials grow, I've had to adapt the layout of the 3–5 references  listed to a single column or 2 column or 3 column, depending on how much space I have remaining to ensure a tight fit.

A simple mockup to show what I mean:

[image]

Now I don't update/send out CVs every day (at most, maybe once a year), so I've gotten by with manual adjustments of spacing and using tables. However, this is not a solution that I like or is particularly elegant.

My question is — is it possible to create a grid on-the-fly, based on the dimensions given? For example, I would like to be able to do:

```
\begin{refList}[2]
    \refItem{
        John Smith\\
        Department of Foo\\
        Quxington University\\
        jsmith@quxington.edu
     }

    \refItem{...}
\end{refList}
```

where the references are simply given as "items" and I can choose how many (equal width) columns to use by changing `[2]` to something else (the number of rows is automatically determined from the number of `refItem`s and the number of columns). There is no need to check if the items will fit in the column, because I obviously won't be using a crazy number like `[5]` on my CV, which will squish/overflow/truncate the entries.

While I think such a system would be nice, I don't know where to begin (or if there are CTAN packages that already do this; a quick search didn't reveal anything). I'm looking for suggestions and help on implementing this/useful packages/etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is nothing fancy, but allows for a flexible `refList` environment that automatically spaces `\refItem`s on a line:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\newcommand{\refItem}[2][l]{% \refItem[<align>]{<reference>}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}\hfill}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{% \email{<email>}
  \href{mailto:#1}{\ttfamily #1}}%
\newenvironment{refList}
  {\null\hfill}
  {\null\par}
\begin{document}

\begin{refList}
  \refItem{John Smith \\ Department of Foo \\ Quxington University \\ \email{jsmith@quxington.edu}}
  \refItem{Jane Doe \\ Department of Bar \\ Bazville University \\ \email{jdoe@ubazville.edu}}
  \refItem{Jack B.\ Nimble \\ Department of Bar \\ Quxington University \\ \email{jbn@quxington.edu}}
\end{refList}
\bigskip
\begin{refList}
  \refItem[c]{John Smith \\ Department of Foo \\ Quxington University \\ \email{jsmith@quxington.edu}}
  \refItem[r]{Jane Doe \\ Department of Bar \\ Bazville University \\ \email{jdoe@ubazville.edu}}
\end{refList}
\bigskip
\begin{refList}
  \refItem{John Smith \\ Department of Foo \\ Quxington University \\ \email{jsmith@quxington.edu}}
  \refItem{Jane Doe \\ Department of Bar \\ Bazville University \\ \email{jdoe@ubazville.edu}}
  \refItem{Jack B.\ Nimble \\ Department of Bar \\ Quxington University \\ \email{jbn@quxington.edu}} \par\medskip\null\hfill
  \refItem{John Smith \\ Department of Foo \\ Quxington University \\ \email{jsmith@quxington.edu}}
  \refItem{Jane Doe \\ Department of Bar \\ Bazville University \\ \email{jdoe@ubazville.edu}}
\end{refList}

\end{document}
```

`\refItem[<align>]{<reference>}` sets `<reference>` like a regular `tabular`, where you can override the default `l`eft alignment (either `c`entred or `r`ight-aligned, as in the second `refList`). As is visible in the MWE above, you don't need to specify the number of columns.

`\email{<email>}` is meant to specify an email using the traditional [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) interface. You can, of course, play with the `hyperref` link settings to suit your needs. See the [`hyperref` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html) for details.

---

Here's an alternative solution that uses [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) and required user input in terms of the columns:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,tabularx,array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{hyperref,tabularx,array}
\newcommand{\refItem}[2][l]{% \refItem[<align>]{<reference>}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}\hfill}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{% \email{<email>}
  \href{mailto:#1}{\ttfamily #1}}%
\newenvironment{refList}[1]
  {\noindent\tabularx{\linewidth}{@{}*{#1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X@{}}}}% \begin{refList}
  {\endtabularx\par}% \end{refList}
\begin{document}

\begin{refList}{3}
  \refItem{John Smith \\ Department of Foo \\ Quxington University \\ \email{jsmith@quxington.edu}} &
  \refItem{Jane Doe \\ Department of Bar \\ Bazville University \\ \email{jdoe@ubazville.edu}} &
  \refItem{Jack B.\ Nimble \\ Department of Bar \\ Quxington University \\ \email{jbn@quxington.edu}}
\end{refList}
\bigskip
\begin{refList}{2}
  \refItem[c]{John Smith \\ Department of Foo \\ Quxington University \\ \email{jsmith@quxington.edu}} &
  \refItem[r]{Jane Doe \\ Department of Bar \\ Bazville University \\ \email{jdoe@ubazville.edu}}
\end{refList}
\bigskip
\begin{refList}{3}
  \refItem{John Smith \\ Department of Foo \\ Quxington University \\ \email{jsmith@quxington.edu}} &
  \refItem{Jane Doe \\ Department of Bar \\ Bazville University \\ \email{jdoe@ubazville.edu}} &
  \refItem{Jack B.\ Nimble \\ Department of Bar \\ Quxington University \\ \email{jbn@quxington.edu}} \\
  \refItem{John Smith \\ Department of Foo \\ Quxington University \\ \email{jsmith@quxington.edu}} &
  \refItem{Jane Doe \\ Department of Bar \\ Bazville University \\ \email{jdoe@ubazville.edu}}
\end{refList}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this one, but would it be possible to make the number of columns fixed (manually input) and equal width?

Comment: @LoremIpsum: I've updated the answer with a [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) option where you manually specify the number of columns.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `multicol`  package in combination with a `trivlist`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{trivlist}
\item John Smith\\
Department of Foo\\
Quxington University\\
jsmith@quxington.edu\\

\item John Smith\\
Department of Foo\\
Quxington University\\
jsmith@quxington.edu\\

\item John Smith\\
Department of Foo\\
Quxington University\\
jsmith@quxington.edu\\

\end{trivlist}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

You can change the`{3}` in  `\begin{multicols}{3}` to as many columns as you wish and of course one can combine the `trivlist` and `multicols` into a user defined environment.

Comment: That solution doesn't automatically cope with items that are too wide for a threecolumn setup.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I am sure improvements can be added. One would think something that can use your `ragged2e` package. However, the OP indicated manual breaks. I just don't like tabulars for this sort of problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: I like the idea here, but multi-cols doesn't seem to handle columns fewer than 3 in the MWE above. For instance, if I change it to 1 or 2, I get this output: http://i.stack.imgur.com/K9lR5.png

Comment: @LoremIpsum The 2 should work (as per your image). For one just omit the multicolumn