# Variant irregular size grid layout

Tags: spacing, packages, grids, grid-typesetting

I am currently preparing for an exam to which we are allowed to bring 1 sheet of paper. Naturally, I want to fit as much information as possible on it.

The information that I need are a bunch of (pseudo code) algorithms. Right now I am using multicolumn on minipages to space them out evenly, which works very well for the maths part of the sheet,  but now I want to fit the whole algorithm without column break to read it nicely. I have looked at [this question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98424/flexible-grid-layout-to-list-addresses), but my problem is that all the grid cells have a different length and width, similar to a [handwritten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEHtb.jpg) sheet.

How can I set this up in Latex? It should be able to cope with mathmode and lstlistings. 
How can I tell multicols when to stark a new column? This would be my fallback solution.

Comment: Please include the code you have up to this point in an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/30280), as it is impossible for us to guess your current setup.

Comment: I need a new setup, my previous one is not doing it for me except for space removal on the sides. 
What I need is a setup that can produce a grid like the handwritten sheet I posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `paracol` package. One switch to column number  by typing `\switchcolumn[<n-1>]` (the first column is 0).

Note: order is not important (example 2)

**Update** `\columnratio{value1,value2,...,\value<n-1>}` set column width where value is ration `column width = valuei* text erea with`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[scale=.98]{geometry}

\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
\columnratio{.3,.2,.2,.2} % {col1,col2,...,col<n-1>} here 4 values
\begin{paracol}{5}
%this is column 1 
\lipsum[1] 
\switchcolumn[1]
%this is column 2 
\lipsum[1-2]
\switchcolumn[2]
%this is column 3 
\lipsum[1-2]
\switchcolumn[3]
%this is column 4 
\lipsum[1]
\switchcolumn[4]
%this is column 5 
\lipsum[1]
\switchcolumn[0]
%this is column 1
\hrule\textbf{back to first column} 
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{paracol}

% example 2
\columnratio{.3,.1,.4} % here 3 values
\begin{paracol}{4}
%this is column 1 
\lipsum[1] 
\switchcolumn[3]
%this is column 4 
\lipsum[1-2]
\switchcolumn[2]
%this is column 3  
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there an option for uneven column length? like first cell in a row 50% of the space, the next two 25% each?

Comment: @RunOrVeith you need to set `\columnratio{.5,.25}\begin{paracol}{3}` see update.